# Как разделить строку на части и присвоить значения

Tags: c++, arduino

В монитор порта вводится 3 числа в таком виде: 241 255 124
Мне нужно разделить эту строку на отдельные числа и присвоить к разным переменным
На выходе должно получиться так: R=241 G=255 B=124
Помогите,пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
strins s("241 255 124");
istringstream ss(s);
int r,g,b;
ss >> r >> g >> b;
```